# Color conventions for side (wheel) reflectors (yellow and white)

Tags: legal, lighting

Spoke reflectors, as far as I know, often come in two colors: yellow and white.

[image: Yellow and white reflectors]

**Is there a convention as to which one should go on the back wheel and which one should go on the front wheel?**

For instance, on cars, [front lights are suppose to emit white or amber light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_lighting#Front_position_lamps), and [rear lights are supposed to emit red light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_lighting#Rear_position_lamps_(tail_lamps)). Is there some convention for bikes as well, like "Front = White, Rear = Yellow"?

I am aware of [this post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/44215), but I don't think there is any *legal* obligation as to which goes where. So, is this just a convention, and if yes, which one?

Comment: This will also vary by location.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but reasonably relevant: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44215/what-are-your-countrys-rules-or-regulations-for-the-colors-of-reflectors-or-lig

Comment: In my country they will (or at least should) go in the bin and only rim or tire reflectors are allowed on the wheels.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for the pointer. I was aware of this post, which I linked in my question.

Comment: @Willeke Spoke reflectors that clip-on are far superior.. highly recommended.  They're all white.

Comment: @Criggie, I do not talk about better or not, I talk about legal or not. Spoke reflectors are illegal here, though mostly ignored by police. That is why the country is important in questions like this.

Comment: It much depends on local laws, some stipulate white, others orange while others still allow both colours.

Comment: @Willeke *Spoke reflectors are illegal here*  That seems a bit strange and even a bit misguided.  Why make it illegal to make a bicycle **more** visible?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ask the Dutch government. At these time a lot of the kids and some of the adults have lights in the wheels, and those are actually acted against. Something like 'distracting drivers'.

Comment: @Willeke That's really funny. Because, just one country away, in Germany, those spoke reflectors are required (two per wheel, all four yellow). Maybe that's why your police is not acting on this: This particular rule clearly reduces the safety of bikes, and many bikes that cross the borders have those reflectors. I agree though, that non-standard lights clipped onto spokes are likely distracting. Like anything else that's out-of-the-ordinary and does not speak the generally accepted code (like white lights front, red lights back, yellow for spoke and pedal reflectors).

Comment: Our government has clearly decided that rim or tire reflectors are better visible and less distracting and do not ask me why.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that sounds like a fresh question - "where are spoke reflectors illegal, optional, or mandatory?"

Comment: IMHO there's a confusion coming up here: There are spoke reflectors like those in OP's picture and spoke reflectors that look like drinking straws made of reflective material that you clip on at one per spoke.

Comment: In the UK you can only use amber reflectors on the front and back of each pedal, white reflector on the front and red reflector on the back both either centrally mounted or to the offside. They also have to be a certain distance from the ground along with front and rear lights. Although this sounds like an answer it's only really valid to the UK.

Comment: @DanK Thanks, that's already helpful, and looks like a convention. Do you have any link to an "official" regulation? I also read from your answer that you don't have a use for yellow reflectors, correct?